# Definition of "some" in this case

Tags: word-usage, word-in-context, word-meaning

I would like to know what definition does "**some**" have in these sentences:

- Some friends you have! *(bad friends that didn't come to the rescue)*
- Some soup you've made! *(delicious soup)*
- Some winter we have this year! *(a very cold winter, unnaturally cold)*
- Some night it was! *(a very interesting and joyful night; there was a lot of fun)*

But depending on the intonation the meaning can change:

- Some friends you have! *(they helped you build a house)*
- Some soup you've made! *(it was really awful, you never made this bad a soup)*
- Some winter we have this year! *(a strange winter. It's not cold. There's no snow.)*
- Some night it was! *(I couldn't sleep. I was up all night and I had a sick stomach)*

So what does **some** mean and how does it work here?

Comment: Whether it expresses appreciation or depreciation is all in the intonation of the sentence (in context).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When used as a determiner before a noun, especially at the beginning of a sentence, *some* may have the trait of anger or disapproval.

At the same time, again, used before a noun it may show how good something or someone is.

So all your examples may work both ways, depending on your or the reader's way of looking at or thinking about something in the context of the actual situation.

Answer (score 3):

When used this way, "some" means remarkable or noteworthy in either a positive or negative way. The positive or negative sense is often taken from context, though there may be an explanatory word, as in "This is some cold winter we're having." There is always the possibility that the speaker is being sarcastic, so the "some cold winter" comment might be heard on a warm day in January.